# Activity crashes in setContentView(), is something wrong with the layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating a new menu that appears when my player dies. The activity does not load and the app crashes at the indicated line below. All my other activities work perfectly fine and I tried to follow the other activities as best as I could but it still doesn't work.

The activity class:

```
public class DeathScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    //define buttons
    private Button btn_replay;
    private Button btn_menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hide title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Hide top bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.deathscreen);

        btn_replay = findViewById(R.id.btn_replay);
        btn_menu = findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
    }

    //invoke callback event in view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btn_replay:
            intent.setClass(this, GamePage.class);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_menu:
            intent.setClass(this, Mainmenu.class);
            break;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The Logcat:

```
 projectname.companyname.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: projectname.companyname.com.myapplication, PID: 12025
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{projectname.companyname.com.myapplication/projectname.companyname.com.myapplication.DeathScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
      at projectname.companyname.com.myapplication.DeathScreen.onCreate(DeathScreen.java:29)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
      at projectname.companyname.com.myapplication.DeathScreen.onCreate(DeathScreen.java:29) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 58286092 byte allocation with 16777168 free bytes and 52MB until OOM
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
      at projectname.companyname.com.myapplication.DeathScreen.onCreate(DeathScreen.java:29) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/death_screen"
    tools:context="projectname.companyname.com.myapplication.DeathScreen">

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_replay"
       android:layout_width="150dip"
       android:layout_height="40dip"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="150dip"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:onClick="onClick"
       android:background="@drawable/replay_button" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
       android:layout_width="150dip"
       android:layout_height="40dip"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:onClick="onClick"
       android:background="@drawable/mainmenu_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or tips to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Clean the project and try again.

Comment: @azizbekian i tried that but it still crashes

Comment: Check your image sizes

Comment: **death_screen** killing your app! ;) That's a funny coincidence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stacktrace, the original issue is

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 58286092 byte allocation with 16777168 free bytes and 52MB until OOM

That sounds like an image that's so large your device doesn't have enough memory to create it. Try removing this line from your activity layout's root view:

> ```
> android:background="@drawable/death_screen"
> ```

If you can successfully run the app after deleting this attribute, you'll know that the problem is that this image consumes too much memory. At that point, there are tons of questions/answers on this site that deal with images + memory consumption.

Comment: Are most instances of this issue caused by images?

Comment: @Ryolu in my personal experience, yes. It's really easy to accidentally go OOM with a high-res image, though of course there are other ways too.